# Exporting Objects Via sys.modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-3.3

1. I like small, self-contained modules, that sometimes contain a single class or a single function, e.g.

   ```
   def decorator(function):
       return function
   ```
2. By convention, I use full, absolute imports only, e.g.

   ```
   # Yes
   import module
   module.function()

   # No
   from module import function
   function()
   ```

Together, this might become annoyingly verbose, e.g.

```
import decorator

@decorator.decorator
def function():
    pass
```

So I like to export things other than modules via `sys.modules`, e.g.

```
import sys

def decorator(function):
    return function

sys.modules[__name__] = decorator
```

And then,

```
import decorator

@decorator
def function():
    pass
```

This was the intro; whether I should do this or not is not the issue. The issue is this strange behaviour:

```
# foo.py

import sys

x = 1

def foo():
    print(x)

sys.modules[__name__] = foo
```

And then,

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo()
None
```

And stranger still, this only happens in Python 2.7; in Python 3.4 it works as expected! My question is, why does this happen, and how can I make this work in Python 2.7?

Thanks.